# How to enable alphanumeric sender ID in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I've recently created a Twilio account and upgraded it (i.e. added credit card and funded). However, when I go to the SMS settings, it still states that alphanumeric sender ID is disabled. The setting description says "Please note the Alpha Numeric Sender Ids will be auto-enabled once you upgrade the account" but this doesn't appear to be the case:

[image: Screenshot of General SMS Settings]

I've tried to see if I can use alpha senders regardless and it seems not. Trying to add an alpha sender to a sender pool gets to me this:

[image]

But the link for "request for enabling the feature here" is https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/alphasender/request which just redirects me to the console home page.

I've checked the doucmentation but it only mentions checking that this setting is enabled - nothing more about how to enable the setting.

Is there anything else I need to do to enable alphanumeric sender IDs?

Comment: As Steve has said, best bet to get your account enabled is to speak to your sales rep or support. Meanwhile I am raising the issue that the link goes to the wrong place, so hopefully this won't be an issue for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your country's telecom laws, specialized SMS sender IDs like short-codes may have application processes attached to them that are outside of a regular paid Twilio account.

Talk to your Twilio account rep or failing that, reach out to Twilio support.

If you [click through](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) to the support article, you can see the support for your country.